# string formating using 2 strings in wpf xaml solution

Tags: c#, wpf, string, xaml, string-formatting

I have 2 string variables var1,var 2 .I need to show

```
For information on returns and exchanges please visit {var 1} or call  {var2}.
```

any xaml solution available for that?.

Comment: So how you store 2 variables in XAML? Put them in Resources? BTW using StringFormat usually involves Binding here.

Comment: I use putting my sentence in resources and my variables in viewmodel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `MultiBinding`, like this:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="For information on returns and exchanges please visit {0} or call {1}.">
            <Binding Path="SomeProperty"/>
            <Binding Path="SomeOtherProperty"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Note that the `SomeProperty` and `SomeOtherProperty` are simple bindings to the `DataContext` of the `TextBlock`, such as the **View Model** or underlying **Model**.